# Microsoft Bot Framework Removing "Edited" annotation on message when updating bot message

Tags: botframework, microsoft-teams, bot-framework-composer

I have built a MS Teams chatbot along with middleware that successfully proactively updates messages through a REST controller (I pass the conversation ID and activity ID to this REST endpoint).

I tested my implementation and everything works great except for this annoying

[image]

"Edited" header that appears. Functionally, it's not too important but the OCD in me wants to get rid of it. I'm wondering if I can get rid of this header by modifying any parameters of my Activity when passing the Activity through UpdateActivityAsync.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I am aware, the only way to update a message previously sent by the bot and *not* have it display the `Edited` flag is to use adaptive cards with Universal Actions and even then only when the card was updated from an action button on the card (with `Action.Execute`).

You can send content to Teams as a plain text message or an adaptive card - with adaptive cards you can use the new-ish universal action model as documented here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/task-modules-and-cards/cards/universal-actions-for-adaptive-cards/overview?tabs=mobile.

This model exists to give you the chance to ensure that a card has the most up-to-date content when being viewed (even after closing and re-opening the chat using the "refresh model") and also allows you to display contextual content for the current user if you're in a group or channel chat... this seems to have the *subjectively* nice side effect that when you update the card using the `InvokeResponse` after submitting content (by implementing/overriding `OnAdaptiveCardInvoke` depending on your language of choice), even though you can send brand new card content as an attachment in the response which updates the card in-place, it doesn't say "Edited" and doesn't even change the timestamp on the message.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions, but the problem with my use case is that the message is proactive. I am trying to implement a file upload adaptive card, where a user uploads a file to a company file system (it cannot be sharepoint), then calls the chatbot endpoint to update the card saying the upload has failed / completed / update upload % status. I have other long running tasks other than this that require proactive messaging to update cards as well. It would be great if MS Teams supported an option to not have the Edited annotation pop up for these cases.

Comment: This behaviour seems to be by design. To achieve your requirements, we recommend you give your feedback in Teams [UserVoice](https://feedbackportal.microsoft.com/feedback/forum/ad198462-1c1c-ec11-b6e7-0022481f8472). 
Microsoft will always focus on customer’s feedback and experience. Some new features would be added to the services based on customers' feedback in the future, and your good ideas will be very helpful for them to improve the service.